ABAP: Generate class with SEO_CLASS_CREATE_COMPLETE with pretty printer
I'm using the Function Module SEO_CLASS_CREATE_COMPLETE to generate classes, but the problem is, that it doesn't do Pretty-print on the source code.
Q:

Is there a way to make the FM do Pretty-print?

Alternatively, is there a way to read the new generated class source, do pretty-print, and save it again?

Alternatively, is there a better way (FM's, classes...) to generate classes, which includes automatic Pretty-print?
CALL FUNCTION 'SEO_CLASS_CREATE_COMPLETE'
  EXPORTING
    devclass          = 'ZDKD_POSTING_AREA'   "Package
    version           = seoc_version_active
    authority_check   = seox_true
    overwrite         = seox_true
    method_sources    = gt_method_sources
    lifecycle_manager = lr_lifecycle_manager
  CHANGING
    class             = wa_vseoclass
    inheritance       = wa_vseoextend
    attributes        = gt_attributes
    methods           = gt_methods
    parameters        = gt_parameters
    exceps            = gt_exceptions.




Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question is similar to: Generate Program whith Pretty Printer Automatically. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. EDIT: the code to beautify is in the parameter METHOD_SOURCES, you may beautify each method implementation via the answer given in the link.
